# D3.js Debt Clock?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to convert my d3.js timer clock into a numerical debt clock.

Here is the type of counter I'm trying to replicate http://www.usdebtclock.org/

I'm not drawing on any real data I just need it to count starting at N and then increasing infinitely. The code block I forked from currently has an actual clock timer  but it's not what I need and there haven't been any good infinite counters for numerical values that i've found. Here is what I currently have for the clock bit:

```
setInterval(update(), 100); 
  var marginLeft = windowWidht/6;
  var marginTop = windowHeight/3 + windowHeight/2.5;
  var textY = 10;           

  var clockGroup = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate("+[marginLeft, marginTop]+")") ;      

  var clockRect = clockGroup.append("rect")
    .attr({
      "width":"70%",
      "height":windowWidht/10,
      "fill":"#C0C0C0",
      "fill-opacity": 0.8
    })

var clockText = clockGroup.append("text")
    .attr({
      "x":"10",
      "y":windowWidht/11,
      "font-size": 110,
      "fill":"#ffffff",
      "stroke":"#000000",
      "stroke-width": 3,
      "font-weight":"bold",
      "font-family":"arial",
      "line-height": 1.5,
      "letter-spacing": 5,
      "word-spacing": 5  
    });

  setInterval(function() {
    clockText.text(moment().format('H:mm:ss:SS'));  
  }, 500)
});
})();
```

How can I adapt this in a way so that it appears like a debt clock and not like a regular clock? (this is part of a much bigger block of code, the debt clock is just a small snip)

Comment: Stack snippets are for **running code** only. I just edited your question for regular code.